# ExtJS Ajax Request params not making it to server

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, httprequest

I have some ExtJS that isn't behaving as expected.  The request (see below) sets the params correctly and have been verified with the FireFox network tool as being in the form data.  The problem arises on the server end.  The server (IIS) doesn't show the parameters in the resulting HttpRequest object.

```
 Ext.Ajax.request(
{
    url: this.url,
    params: { note: this.currentNote.data.Note, noteId: this.currentNote.data.NoteId, forceClose: doClose },
    method: 'POST',
    scope: this,
    success: function(response, options)
    {
        var result = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        if (result)
        {
            ... Do Stuff ...
        }
    },
    failure: function()
    {
        this.getEl().unmask();
        Ext.Msg.alert('Note was NOT saved', "Note was NOT saved.");
    }
});
```

As indicated above, the HttpRequest.Params object does NOT contain note, noteId, or 
forceClose.  It does, however, contain the query string items that are attached to the URL.

Comment: If you can see them being passed in FF then the problem doesn't relate to Ext.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea but it might be `request filter` problem.

[IIS Request Filtering](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering)

1. On the taskbar, click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Server Manager.
2. In the Server Manager hierarchy pane, expand Roles, and then click Web Server (IIS).
3. In the Web Server (IIS) pane, scroll to the Role Services section, and then click Add Role Services.
4. On the Select Role Services page of the Add Role Services Wizard, select Request Filtering, and then click Next.

[image]
5. On the Confirm Installation Selections page, click Install.
6. On the Results page, click Close.